# Odoo 10 how to display products for inventory

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am run a website with multi warehouses .

Odoo 10 by default shows the products when we click on warehouse locations , not when we click on warehouses itself  , am searching for a solution so that when i click on single warehouse, I can see all the products related for that warehouse from all it locations ?

We have a model 
stock.change.product.qty 
Filed : Location_id(Many2one)
Filed : product_id (Many2one)

And the inventory model:
stock.warehouse
Filed : view_location_id (Many2one)

I dont know how to do that with odoo ,Any idea please ? Thank you

Comment: You can go to the products view and make an advanced search writing the warehouse you want to check. You can save that filter as favourite

Comment: @ChesuCR Thank you for your Answer , I tried to make a filler like Werehouse contain whorehouse name , id , and is equal to but nothing work with me